# from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: .net-core, angular8

I am calling a web service in Angular 8 and the two URLs are not the same.

> Error -> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'http://localhost:51891/api/Admin/Login' from origin
>   'http://localhost:4200'`enter code here` has been blocked by CORS
>   policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control
>   check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple
>   values 'http://localhost:4200, *', but only one is allowed.

I put this code in my startup file:

```
services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
            builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                .WithOrigins(http://localhost:4200, http://localhost:51891/api)
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
        );

});
app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
```